# OAUTH2 - Fitbit using requests_oauthlib

Tags: python, django

**Context**

> I am writing a python/django application which accesses Fitbit data.

**Problem**

> To access a users data I must get their token for which can be used repeatably to access fitness data. The following goes through the current steps.

---

**1. Firstly I present the user with a link:**

```
def register_2(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():

        oauth = OAuth2Session(
                auth_2_client_id,
                redirect_uri    = redirect_uri,
                scope           = fitbit_scope)

        authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(fitbit_url_authorise_2)

        return render_to_response('register.html',{
                "authorization_url" : authorization_url
            },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

---

**2. User goes to Fitbit, logs into their account and authorises access.**

---

**3. The user is then returned to my site with a code that should allow me to get the token.**

```
def callback_2(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        code = request.GET.get('code')
        state = request.GET.get('state')

        oauth = OAuth2Session(
                client_id               = auth_2_client_id,
                redirect_uri            = redirect_uri
                )

        token = oauth.fetch_token(
                code                    = code,
                token_url               = fitbit_url_access_2,
                authorization_response  = request.build_absolute_uri()
                )
```

Once `callback_2` is called I get the error:

```
(missing_token) Missing access token parameter.
```

**Resources**:

[Fitbit OAUTH2 API](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/OAuth+2.0)

[OAuth2Session Docs](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Found a way around this. Pretty simple after all the effort of research. The following is a custom method using `requests.post()` and `base64.b64encode()`.

```
def callback_2(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        code    = request.GET.get('code')
        state   = request.GET.get('state')

        url     = fitbit_url_access_2
        data    = "client_id="      + auth_2_client_id      + "&" +\
                  "grant_type="     + "authorization_code"  + "&" +\
                  "redirect_uri="   + redirect_uri_special  + "&" +\
                  "code="           + code

        headers     = {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(auth_2_client_id + ':' + consumer_secret),
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

        r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers).json()
```

Comment: With python3, I needed to convert the client_id:client_secret string to utf-8 before b64 encoding, then decode from utf-8 back to a string. e.g., `toConvert = client_id + ':' + client_secret`, `encoded = base64.b64encode(toConvert.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")`, `headers  = {      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded, ...`